# Activated virtual environment using incorrect Python executable

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, virtualenv

I am working on a project through PyCharm. When I started the project, the project interpreter was a newly created virtualenv located in my project folder at `/path/to/project_folder/venv` and using base interpreter `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

When working in PyCharm, the Python Console seems to be using the right venv/Python executable etc. Running `os.system("which python")` returns `/usr/bin/python`.

Next, I activate this venv through my terminal (on Ubuntu 18.04) using the command `source /path/to/project_folder/venv/bin/activate` which works fine and shows me that it is activated with a `(venv)`. However, if I run `which python`, it returns `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`.

Why is this occurring? How can I access the same Python interpreter from the PyCharm console through my Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: /usr/bin/python is probably a symbolic link to /usr/bin/python3.6 which means in your pycharm environment you're actually using your system python and not a virtualenv. The interpreter for your venv should reside in /path/to/project_folder/venv/Scripts. When you're sourcing your venv manually you're falling back to your anaconda3 interpreter, it seems to me you've got a couple of interpreters installed in your machine and it's causing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the interpreter for the venv is at `/path/to/project_folder/venv/bin/python` even though running `os.system("which python")` returns `/usr/bin/python`. The reason I think so is because if I activate the venv and then, instead of running `python` (which lands me into the anaconda interpreter), I run `/path/to/project_folder/venv/bin/python`, I enter an interpreter which is identical to the PyCharm one it seems. I am able to import all the site packages etc. that belong to venv. I don't know why running `python` doesn't take me straight to the venv interpreter...

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me in a specific project.

**Symptoms:**

- No executable taken from the venv; i.e:
- `which python3` from bash is not taken from venv
- Python packages are not working from venv

**Cause:**

- You renamed your project folder
- Virtual environment PATH keeps old path to venv
- It fails silently

**Solutions:**

1. Create a new venv and reinstall requirements, OR
2. Rename folder to its old name

Change `PATH` is not the solution. `venv` script creates some other routes in various files.

Note: Tested with `python3 -m venv venv`